# Error when add python file to pyscript in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pyscript

I got an issue when import python file to py-script with pyscript

I want to use pyscript in my React project.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlText }}></div>

const htmlText = `
<py-script src='demo.py'></py-script>
<div id="outputRepl"></div>
<py-repl output="outputRepl"> </py-repl>
`;
```

demo.py

```
import datetime as dt

def show_time(): 
    Element("today").write(str(dt.date.today()))

show_time()
```

But, I still got the error like bellow, I try many way to fixed but it is didn't work.

[image]